# Calculating Probabilities - How to manage 'share of packets arriving'

Tags: probability

At a multi-port  switch  S, packets may arrive via  four  different input  ports P1, …,  P4 and are switched to different output ports.  The table below shows which percentage/share of 
the  arriving packets each input port  carries and the switching  error probability for  each 
input port.

```
input-port  share-of-arriving-packets  switching-error-probability
P1                 10%                           0.05
P2                 20%                           0.0003
P3                 30%                           0.0001
P4                 40%                           0.0004
```

What is the probability that an arbitrary arriving packet is switched correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C$ be the event that an arriving packet is switched correctly. Then

$$P(C)=\sum_{i=1}^4P(P_i)P(C|P_i)=0.1\cdot0.95+0.2\cdot0.9997+0.3\cdot0.9999+0.4\cdot0.9996.$$